# Maintaining different states of model in angularjs

Tags: service, angularjs, model

The application I'm trying to build has a fixed topnavbar, a left panel, and a right panel. The right panel displays a list of recommended products, unique to each user, and the left panel has two parts - a cart list, showing products added, and a tab of users.

What I want to do is maintain states between different users, i.e, if I click on a user tab, I should see a list of products on the right, unique to him, and he should be able to add these to the cart list that is displayed on the left, and if I switch to another user, it must show new products and corresponding cart list (if he has already added or show empty).

Also, there must be a two way interaction between left and right panel, that is if I click a product that is added to the cart, I should be able to see a list of recommended products on the right.

For demo sake, I'm just using a JSON to store the products, no server interaction.

Implementing this using two controllers and a service proved to be a little difficult to me. How can I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

There's two things I think you need to learn about to do this more easily 1 is routeProviders, 2 is ng-include.

The routeProvider will allow you to have a "top level navigation" to different HTML "partials", it will map a URL to a view essentially.  I haven't done anything too complex yet, but from what I understand the way to deal with another level of navigation or sub-views is to use the ng-include directive.

I've also used a bit of code to restore a value in my model when the page loads (I use the $location service to get information about the URL this property on the model in turn causes some classes to be set on the navigation elements to highlight the current page).

Here's my full "seed" code I've been using for a couple of projects that works nicely:

```
var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", []);

// mainApp.run(function($rootScope, $location, $anchorScroll, $routeParams) {
//   //when the route is changed scroll to the proper element.
//   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(newRoute, oldRoute) {
//      if(document.documentElement.clientWidth>=600)
//          return;
//     $location.hash("contentArea");
//     $anchorScroll();  
//   });
// });

mainApp.controller("NavigationCtrl", function ($scope, $location,$anchorScroll) {
    $scope.currentPage = "home";
    $scope.pages = [
                    {label:'Home', location:'home'},
                    {label:'Page2', location:'page2'}
                    ];
    $scope.gotoPage = function(item) {
        $scope.currentPage = item.location;
        $location.path("/"+item.location)
    };

    $scope.initialize = function() {
        $scope.currentPage = $location.path().substring(1);
    };


    $scope.goHome = function() {
        $scope.currentPage = "home";
        $location.path("/home")
    };

    $scope.itemClass = function(item) {
        return item.location === $scope.currentPage ? 'active' : undefined;
    };
});

mainApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
        when("/", {templateUrl:'partials/home.html'}).
        when("/home", {templateUrl:'partials/home.html'}).
        when("/page2", {templateUrl:'partials/secondPage.html'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:"/"});
});
```

In the HTML

```
<header>
<div id="headerRegion">
    <a ng-click="goHome()">
        <div id="logoWrapper">
            <img src="images/logoBig.png" id="headerLogo" alt="Intellect-Tech Logo">
        </div>
        <div id="companyName">
            Company name goes here
        </div>
        <div id="slogan">
            <i>Slogan goes here</i>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</header>
<nav ng-init="initialize()">
    <div id="pointerContainer">
        <img src="images/navPointer.png" id="navPointer" class="{{currentPage}}"/>
    </div>
    <div id="navText">
        <ol>
            <li ng-click="gotoPage(item)" ng-repeat="item in pages" ng-class="itemClass(item)">
                {{item.label}}
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</nav>
```

If you'd like I can post this to github and get you a link, I've been intending to get it on there anyhow.  This code is by no means perfect, but is a work in progress and has helped me to jump start into quite a few projects at once without many headaches.